# Cryptogram Puzzle

Tags: python

I'm still learning Python, but thought this was kinda a cool project to work on. Feel free to critique and let me know what to work on or change.

main.py

```
# -------- MODULE IMPORTS --------
import random
# -------- CLASS IMPORTS --------
from phrases import Phrases

# -------- GLOBAL VARIABLES --------

p_p = Phrases.phrases
ref = Phrases.phrases[1]
p_a = Phrases.alpha
phrase_picked = 0
p_unique_letters = []
p_unique_nums = []
converted_phrase = ""

""" 
    THIS FUNCTION GENERATES A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 1 & 26
    (NUMBER OF LETTERS IN THE ALPHABET)
"""
def get_rand_num():
    r = random.randint(1, 26)
    return r


"""
    THIS FUNCTION TAKES THE ORIGINAL PHRASE AND
    ITERATES OVER EVERY LETTER AND CHANGES IT TO
    A RANDOM LETTER BASED ON THE RANDOM NUMBER 
    THAT IS ASSIGNED IN THE 'RUN_PUZZLE' FUNCTION
"""
def create_new_p():
    global converted_phrase
    for l in p_p[phrase_picked]:
        if l.lower() in p_unique_letters:
            temp_li = p_unique_letters.index(l.lower())
            temp_ni = p_unique_nums[temp_li] - 1
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + p_a[temp_ni]

        # IF THERE IS A SPECIAL CHARACTER IN THE PHRASE LIKE A PERIOD
        # OR COLON. THESE STATEMENTS WILL NOT CONVERT THE CHARACTER TO
        # A RANDOM CHARACTER

        elif l == '\'':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + "'"
        elif l == '\"':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + '"'
        elif l == ' ':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + ' '
        elif l == '.':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + '.'
        elif l == ',':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + ','
        elif l == ':':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + ':'
        elif l == '-':
            converted_phrase = converted_phrase + '-'

    """ 
        PRINTS OUT THE FINAL CONVERTED PHRASE TO THE CONSOLE
        ALONG WITH THE VERSES REFERENCE WHICH IS IN IT'S ORIGINAL
        SPELLING
    """
    print("\n" + converted_phrase.upper() + "\n\n" + ref)


"""
    THIS FUNCTION ITERATES OVER THE ORIGINAL PHRASE AND PUTS ONLY THE
    **DIFFERENT** CHARACTERS INTO A LIST. EACH CHARACTER IS THEN ASSIGNED
    A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 1 & 26.
"""
def run_puzzle():
    for l in p_p[phrase_picked]:
        if l.lower() not in p_unique_letters and l.lower() in p_a:
            p_unique_letters.append(l.lower())

    p_len = len(p_unique_letters)

    while len(p_unique_nums) < p_len:
        r = get_rand_num()
        if r not in p_unique_nums:
            p_unique_nums.append(r)

    """ UNCOMENT BELOW LINE TO SEE A MORE CLEAR OUTPUT OF HOW
        THE LETTERS ARE ASSIGNED TO A RANDOM NUMBER
    """
    # print(str(p_unique_letters) + ":" + str(p_unique_nums))

    create_new_p()
```

phrases.py

```
# STARTS THE FIRST FUNCTION CALL OF THE PROGRAM
run_puzzle()
class Phrases():

# THIS IS A LIST THAT HOLDS EACH LETTER OF THE ALPHABET INDIVIDUALLY
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
         'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# HOLDS THE CURRENT PHRASE(S) IN A LIST.
# THE FIRST ITEM([0]) IS THE PHRASE
# THE SECOND ITEM([1]) IS THE VERSE REFERENCE
phrases = ["Good will come to those who are generous and lend freely, "
           "who conduct their affairs with justice.", "Psalm - 112:5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've essentially built a glorified [Caesar Cipher](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/). Not all of the changes I suggest below are included in the final version of the reviewed code, but they should be considered. Here they are:

- **Comments**: `#------- IMPORT STATEMENTS ------`, then having one import below it, is a bit verbose. You should only comment code that needs to be explained, like an algorithm or a method.
- **Docstrings**: Docstrings belong inside the method
- **Structure**: There really is not need to have a separate file for `Phrases`. Having an array, or user inputed, for the phrases within the file is good enough.
- **Global Variables**: It's not recommended to use global variables in your code. If it can be passed as a parameter, do it that way.
- **Alphabet**: `string` has it's own stored alphabet, so you can `import string` and use, in your case, `string.ascii_lowercase` for your alphabet.
- **Main guard**: You should wrap any code that isn't in a function in a main guard. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5544783/8968906) is an answer that provides a deeper and more meaningful explanation.
- **Elif Elif Elif**: You had 7 `elif` checking for special characters. You can just use an `else` to catch anything not in the alphabet, and append that.
- **String Formatting**: `print("\n" + converted_phrase.upper() + "\n\n" + ref)` looks very chunky. It can be simplified to `print(f"\n{converted_phrase.upper()}\n\n{ref}")`, utilizing the `f""` string formatting. Using this, you can directly implement variables into strings, instead of using `+` and separating the string.

***Final Code***

```
import random

CHART = {
    97: 'a', 98: 'b', 99: 'c', 100: 'd', 101: 'e', 102: 'f', 103: 'g',
    104: 'h', 105: 'i', 106: 'j', 107: 'k', 108: 'l', 109: 'm', 110: 'n',
    111: 'o', 112: 'p', 113: 'q', 114: 'r', 115: 's', 116: 't', 117: 'u',
    118: 'v', 119: 'w', 120: 'x', 121: 'y', 122: 'z'
}

def create_new_phrase(text, rotations):
    """ Encodes the passed text, rotating `rotations` times """
    new_phrase = ""
    for index in range(len(text)):
        new_position = ord(text[index]) + (rotations % 26)
        if new_position > 122:
            new_position = 97 + (new_position - 122)
        if ord(text[index]) not in CHART:
            new_phrase += text[index]
        else:
            new_phrase += CHART[new_position]
    return new_phrase

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(create_new_phrase("Good will come to those who are generous and lend freely, who conduct their affairs with justice.".lower(), random.randint(1, 24)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A respectable program for someone learning to code with Python.

#### Style

Comments are good when they add useful information to help someone (likely you in the future) understand the code.  MODULE IMPORT, CLASS IMPORTS, and GLOBAL VARIABLES don't really add anything.  In contrast, a comment that explains what a global variable is used for and why it needs to be a global variable would be useful.

The Phrase class doesn't really serve a purpose here. The class attributes aren't really so related as to belong in a class.

Global variables should be avoided if possible.  They represent an interface to functions that is hidden and likely undocumented.  For example, you can't tell from the call `create_new_p()` at the end of `run_puzzle()` that you need to first:

1. set `p_p` to a list of phrases,
2. pick a phrase and store the index of the phrase in `phrase_picked`,
3. set `p_unique_letters` to a list of the unique letters in the picked phrase,
4. set `p_unique_nums` to a list of random integers between 1 and 26 that has the same length as `p_unique_letters`, and
5. set `converted_phrase` to an empty string.

or the function won't run correctly.  It also doesn't show that the result of the call is returned in `converted_phrase`.

Docstrings go inside the function, not before it.  And please, not in all caps.  All uppercase text is actually harder to read than proper mixed case text.

#### Substance

Looking at a call to `get_rand_num()`, you don't know what it returns without inspecting the function.  However, a Python programmer, would readily understand a call to  `random.randint(1, 26)`.  So just use the later.

From the doc string for `create_new_p()` (p for puzzle?), the purpose of the function is to take an input phrase and create a puzzle phrase by mapping the letters to a random permutation of the letters.  For example, 'a' may be mapped to 'x' and 'b' may be mapped to 'e'.  Anything that isn't a letter is unchanged.

```
def create_new_puzzle(phrase, letter_mapping):
    ''' Makes a cryptogram of `phrase` by replacing letters according to
        letter_mapping.  Other characters are unchanged.
    '''

    puzzle_phrase = []

    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.isalpha():
            puzzle_phrase.append(letter_mapping[letter])
        else:
            puzzle_phrase.append(letter)

    return ''.join(puzzle_phrase)
```

In python, strings are immutable. So contcatenating a letter to a string may have to create a new string, copy the old string and the new letter into the new string.  You will frequently see code that creates strings  by appending letters to a list, and then using ''.join() on the list at the end to make a string.

With experience, you will learn to write this as a list comprehension:

```
def create_new_puzzle(phrase, letter_mapping):
    ''' Makes a cryptogram of `phrase` by replacing letters according to
        letter_mapping.  Other characters are unchanged.
    '''

    puzzle_phrase = [letter_mapping.get(letter,letter) for letter in phrase]

    return ''.join(puzzle_phrase)
```

Or, using feature of the standard library, maybe like this:

```
def create_new_puzzle(phrase, letter_mapping):
    ''' Makes a cryptogram of `phrase` by replacing letters according to
        letter_mapping.  Other characters are unchanged.
    '''

    return phrase.translate(str.maketrans(letter_mapping))
```

Notice how the interface for `create_new_puzzle()` is independent from how the function is implemented.  The phrase and mapping are passed in and the cryptogram gets returned.  This is good because you can change the internals of the function without affecting the rest of the program.

`run_puzzle()` goes through a lot of work to build a mapping from the alphabet to a randomized alphabet.  First it collects the unique letters in the phrase, and then associating a unique random number from 1 to 26 to each letter.  This can be improved by realizing that it is unnecessary to get the unique letters or associating the numbers. Instead just build a mapping from the alphabet to a jumbled up version of the alphabet.  This can also be made into a separate function:

```
import random
import string

def create_mapping():
    to_alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    random.shuffle(to_alphabet)

    return dict(zip(string.ascii_letters, to_alphabet*2))
```

I presume phrases is supposed to be a list of phrases, so that one can be picked at random to make a cryptogram puzzle.

```
phrases = [
   ("phrase one", "cite 1"),
   ("phrase two", "cite 2"),
   ... etc.
]
```

So `run_puzzle()` becomes:

```
import phrases

def run_puzzle():
    phrase, citation = random.choice(phrases)
    mapping = create_mapping()
    puzzle_phrase = create_new_puzzle(phrase, mapping)

    print("\n{}\n\n{}".format(puzzle_phrase, citation))
```